# Is Bitcoin mining NP-Hard?

Tags: np-complete, np-hard

I can't find this anywhere online. Is bitcoin mining NP-Hard?

If so, how would we be able to prove a reduction from a known NP-hard problem? I am a bit lost.

Comment: It's difficult to prove such a statement if you only have an intuitive idea as to what "bitcoin mining" is. To prove that a problem X is NP-hard, you have to have formally define X.

Answer (score 4):

No. Bitcoin mining can be solved in $O(1)$ time. Unfortunately the hidden constant is quite large.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible if you could elaborate please? I would really appreciate it.

How do you prove it's constant time?

Comment: There are only finitely many hashes ($2^{256}$). You can just try all of them in constant time.

Comment: I think I get it. Thank you Tom :) 

So computing SHA256 is constant time and we only have a finite number of hashes, so our problem never really scares in any sort of polynomial time. It's simply constant.

Comment: Of course it is a _huge_ constant. To start looking at NP-completeness, or any asymptotic times, you'd have to define a problem involving n-bit "bitcoins", where the bitcoins that are used in practice are the special case for n = 256.

Comment: @gnasher729 It is true that in most cases you would have to look at a generalization. However, most hashing functions (such as SHA-256 used in bitcoin) do not have a commonly accepted natural generalization.

Answer (score 0):

While Tom's answer is correct, I think there is more to be said. For example, there is a finite number of chess positions on an 8x8 board with the 50 moves rules, yet we can sometimes hear statements like "Chess is PSPACE-complete".

In order to study the complexity of such a problem, you have to generalize it, i.e. allow it to have arbitrarily large instances. For chess, a generalized board has size $n\times n$. Note that there may be different ways to generalize a problem, and they may yield different complexities.

If we generalize Bitcoin mining, parameterized by the number of bits oh the hash and the number of bits that you want to be 0 at the start, I think that we get an problem that is in NP (though I'm not sure we can guarantee that there exists a solution of polynomial size).

As for many problems used in cryptography, this problem is not known to be NP-hard: perhaps the structure of SHA256 has a weakness that allows to solve this problem efficiently. Moreover, it is not straightforward to build a reduction from SAT to this problem due to the structure of SHA256: it is not an arbitrary function.

Comment: To be NP-complete or NP-hard, a solution to the problem must also enable you to solve other problems in NP. Being able to solve a bitcoin related problem might not give you any way to solve the Travelling Salesman problem, for example. So it might be practically as hard as any NP-complete problem, but neither NP-complete nor NP-hard.